# Setting "Site sharing settings" programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, microsoft-graph

I am trying to programmatically set the "Site sharing settings" options under "Site Permissions" -> "Change how members can share" screen on a Modern site. I would like to set the site to the middle option. Basically I want Members to be able to share individual folders but not the entire site.

(This is not the same as making a site public/private, and also not the same as the external sharing settings.)

[image]

I would prefer a solution with Microsoft Graph or CSOM but would really be open to any kind of programmatic way to set this (e.g. site designs/site scripts, SharePoint REST API).

The closest thing I have found is the `web.MemberCanShare` bool property in CSOM but that seems to only toggle between the 1st and 3rd options.

Does anyone know how to set this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample script to change site-level sharing settings:

```
#Parameters
$SiteUrl = "<SiteURL>"  
$UserName = "<Account>"  
$Password = "<Passsword>"

#Load Assemblies
$loadInfo1 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client") 
$loadInfo2 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
$loadInfo3 = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles")

#Connection
$Securepass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,$Securepass)

$Web = $context.Web
$AllProperties = $Web.AllProperties
$context.Load($Web)
$context.Load($AllProperties)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

#Change the values for MembersCanShare & AssociatedMemberGroup.AllowMembersEditMembership accordingly
$Web.MembersCanShare = $true
$web.Update();
$web.Context.ExecuteQuery()
$AssociatedMember = $web.AssociatedMemberGroup
$context.Load($AssociatedMember)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$web.AssociatedMemberGroup.AllowMembersEditMembership = $false
$web.AssociatedMemberGroup.Update();
$web.Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

**Note:** This is the second option with

```
$Web.MembersCanShare = $true
$web.AssociatedMemberGroup.AllowMembersEditMembership = $false
```

Also, the script does not change the **Allow requests** settings.

Reference: [Changing the "Allow members to share" SharePoint site Access Requests setting using Office Dev PnP.](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/changing-the-quot-allow-members-to-share-quot-sharepoint-site/m-p/18939/highlight/true#M569)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!